# My rule does not do anything (understandably)

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, rule, argument-patterns

I want a rule that would transform, for example, `And[i,F[j,k],l,G[m,F[j,k],n],p]` into `And[i,F[j,k],l,G[m,T,n],p]`, where `F`, `G` and `T` are either just symbols or, say, defined by `F[u_,v_]:=Or[F1[Or[Not[u],v],F2[v]]` or `G[x_,y_,z_]:=Or[G1[x,y],G2[z,x]]` or `T=H[False,True]` or something even more complicated.

I have defined the following rule:

```
And[u___, x_, v___, y_, w___] :> And[u, x, v, y //. x -> T, w]
```

It never changes any expression. How should I do it properly?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
expr = And[i, F[j, k], l, G[m, F[j, k], n], p];
MapAt[ReplaceAll[#, F[j, k] -> T] &, expr, {4, 2}]

(*  i && F[j, k] && l && G[m, T, n] && p   *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Sorry if this is not clear from the question, but any instances of such situation are needed. More precisely, whenever I have `And[e1,...,en]` which is not further simplifiable, and `e1`, ..., `en` are any expressions whatsoever, I want every occurrence of each `ei` in all of the other `ej` to be replaced by `T`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[F]
in = And[i, F[j, k], l, G[m, F[j, k], n], p]
```

> ```
> i && F[j, k] && l && G[m, F[j, k], n] && p
> ```

```
in2 = And[i, F[j, k], l, G[m, F[j, k], n], Nest[H, F[1], 5] + p]
```

> ```
> i && F[j, k] && l && G[m, F[j, k], n] && p + H[H[H[H[H[F[1]]]]]]
> ```

**1.** You can use `Replace` with level specification `{2, ∞}`:

```
Replace[in, F[__] -> T, {2, ∞}]
```

> ```
> i && F[j, k] && l && G[m, T, n] && p
> ```

```
Replace[in2, F[__] -> T, {2, ∞}]
```

> ```
> i && F[j, k] && l && G[m, T, n] && p + H[H[H[H[H[T]]]]]
> ```

**2.** Alternatively, use [`TagSetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html) to define behavior of `F` inside expressions with designated heads:

```
ClearAll[F];
F /: (head : G | H)[a___, F[__], b___] := head[a, T, b];

in
```

> ```
> i && F[j, k] && l && G[m, T, n] && p
> ```

```
in2
```

> ```
> i && F[j, k] && l && G[m, T, n] && p + H[H[H[H[H[T]]]]]
> ```

Comment: Thanks, this should work. Except that could not I encounter `F` on other levels too? And, in the second version, it will only work in `G`.

Comment: Seems it is my fault, I should formulate the goal more clearly.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, you can use the second approach more generally as (i) `ClearAll[F];
F /: Except[And, head_][a___, F[__], b___] := head[a, T, b];in` or as (ii) `ClearAll[F];
F /: (head : G | H)[a___, F[__], b___] := head[a, T, b];in`

Answer (score 0):

Myself I tried something as general as possible. It would be great if somebody could optimize this, I feel it is far from perfect.

```
step[list_] := Module[{ul = Union[list], l, newl = {}, k, res},
  l = Length[ul];
  For[k = 1, k <= l, k++,
   AppendTo[newl, 
    ul[[k]] /. Table[ul[[j]] -> T, {j, Complement[Range[l], {k}]}]
    ]
   ];
  res = And @@ newl;
  Return[If[Head[res] === And, 
    Table[res[[k]], {k, Length[res]}], {res}]]
  ]
stab[list_] := FixedPoint[step, list]
myAnd[u___] := And @@ stab[{u}]
```